# emacsclient not working for Yamamoto Mitsuharu's OSX pot

Tags: macos, emacs

I am using [Yamamoto Mitsuharu's OSX port of emacs](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port). I would like to run `emacs --daemon` and then open a gui window with emacsclient.

The command `emacsclient -c` opens a terminal instance and `emacsclient -n -c` (with and without the `-c`) does not seem to work, it exits straight away with exit code 141.

I am running OSX 10.9.

Comment: It seems that this is [not supported](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port/blob/master/README-mac#L210) by this port. Thanks to NihilistDandy on reddit for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the system default older version of Emacs.

Symlink the new binary like this:

```
ln -s /Applications/Emacs.app/bin/* /usr/local/bin
```

Then double check with

```
which -a emacs
which -a emacsclient
```

Comment: This is what I thought at first! But I'm not, I am definitely using the emacsclient that comes with the .app

Comment: Not sure then.  How did you install it?

Comment: With homebrew. I tried to reinstall with the `--HEAD` flag but this didn't work. I might build from source at some point.

Comment: No idea then.  There's been a few reports of people having trouble building on OSX on emacs-devel.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not implemented in this version of emacs as you can read about it in the [github issue here](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port/issues/27)